# Unable to remove white spaces and new lines in a string using php regex

Tags: php, regex, string

my string is

```
$str = '             4/151n';
```

My regex is

```
preg_match_all('/[^!$|@|!|#|%|\^|&|*|(|)|_|\–|\-|+|=|\\|\/|{|}|\[0-9\]|.|,|\|:|;|"|\'|\s+|→|<|>|\~\[\\r\\n\\t\]~]/', $str, $matches);
```

My output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => �
    [1] => n
)
```

The output I need is

```
Array
(
    [0] => n
)
```

Let me explain my requirement clearly.
I need to remove all the special characters, numbers, new lines, white spaces from my string. The above regex is working fine for all cases except the above string.

For the above string, I am getting some unknown character in the 0th location. Need to remove that.

Please help me out!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to remove all the special characters, numbers, new lines, white spaces

You can just use:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\P{L}+/u', '', $str);
//=> n
```

Here `\P{L}+` matches 1 or more of non-letters with unicode support.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xR6dQ7/1)

---

**Update:** Based on this comment from OP:

> if I have multiple words in a string, I need to get them in an array

You can use:

```
if (preg_match_all('/\p{L}+/u', $str, $m))
    print_r($m[0]);
```

#### [RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/xR6dQ7/2)

Comment: I am getting 0 as my output for this, not getting `n`

Comment: Works for me. What PHP version are you using? Try: `$str = preg_replace('/\P{L}+/u', '', $str);`

Comment: @anubhava Just noticed that +1 :)

Comment: @anubhava if I have multiple words in a string, I need to get  them in an array. For example, if my string is "       4/151abc!@#n", then my output should be array([0] => abc,[1] => n).  For this, I need to use, preg_match_all, How can I write my regex for that. Hope you understand what I am saying!

Comment: @anubhava ,The final update is working fine for me, can you explain what is p{L} about this?

Comment: As I mentioned on my answer also \p{L} matches and Unicode letter, something that satisfies your requirements.

Comment: @anubhava A little change in my requirement, I need to replace the special characters with space now. If I use this  `preg_replace('/\P{L}+/u', '', $str);` It is replacing the alphabets with spaces. but, I need to replace speacial characters with spaces. Please help me

Comment: Hey, I got it mann. Used this `preg_replace('/[^!\p{L}]+/u', ' ', $string);` working fine for me

Comment: Try: `$str = preg_replace('/\p{P}+/u', ' ', $str);`